# Azure automatically shutting down VM (ShutdownRolesForInternalOffersOperation)

Tags: azure

about 30 minutes after starting my VM, Azure shuts it down and puts it in a Stopped+Deallocated state.

Something is issuing a `ShutdownRoles` operation... In the service management logs I found this

**`<OperationKind>ShutdownRolesForInternalOffersOperation</OperationKind>`**

I'm not sure what a **`ShutdownRolesForInternalOffersOperation`** is and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on this.

How do I prevent this from occurring, or troubleshoot more?

Here is the [log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jonschoning/b5fca9d8d21e54c90180c5476131f113/raw/d9a0d662c61491825e087d0407e97d97b99e7539/ShutdownRolesForInternalOffersOperation)

Comment: Are you by chance running into a quota limit?

Comment: It says I still have $97 credits remaining and I'm only running 1 vm... it's been running for a few hours now.. will still monitor but otherwise curious to the nature of this

Comment: Check your Automation if there is a schedule runbook control this action.

Comment: ShutdownRolesForInternalOffersOperation implies some sort of Azure-initiated task, no?